# Close Div - Fade Out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div at the top of my page with a close button in it, which when clicked makes the div disappear, this is what I want, however I would like to have the div fade out, rather than just go "**POOF**" and it's gone instantly. How would I do this?

Current code:

```
<div class="topimage">
    <span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;'></span>
</div>
```

Top image being the div that disappears, the span being the close button.

I've tried adding `.fadeout()` in there, but that didn't work - or I didn't add it in the correct place, which is probably the case.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: are you using jquery?? if yes then you can just use $('#close').on('click', function(){$('.topImage').fadeOut();});

Comment: Do you want to remove the DOM element (as you're currently doing) or just hide it? jQuery fadeOut is going to end with display:none, not removing it from the DOM.

Comment: the function is spelled `fadeOut()` and you can pass a time in milli seconds parameter `fadeOut(500)` would be half a second

Answer (score 2):

Others are suggesting jQuery,however you don't appear to be using jQuery and this can be done without it.

First I suggest not using the onclick attribute. Keep your JavaScript in your javascript files and your HTML in your HTML files. 
See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

Now the solution is to set a CSS3 transition on your "topimage" div for opacity, then apply a class to it on click that sets its opacity to 0. This will create a fade out effect. Then you can set a timeout to remove the div from the page. Make sure this timeout length matches the CSS3 transition time.

```
HTML:

<div class="topimage">
    <span id='close'>x</span>
</div>
```

```
CSS:

.topimage{
    transition: opacity 500ms;
}
.topimage.fadeOut{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```
JS:

var close = document.querySelector("#close");

close.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var parent = this.parentNode;
    parent.classList.add('fadeOut');
    setTimeout(function(){
        parent.remove();
    }, 500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/swoogie/rcpjnj3f/

Comment: Nice answer. A little trick that could improve this:
.topimage{
transition: opacity 500ms, display 0s;
transition-delay: 0ms, 500ms;
}
.topimage.fadeOut{
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
}

And you can remove the timeout form js. Hope you will like it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, and I am unsure why. I've put my code on pastebin, if you can take a look and maybe spot what is wrong, that would be great:

HTML: http://pastebin.com/E3PLLYTa
CSS: http://pastebin.com/JjLixJJY

I have a feeling it's something to do with the hover on the close button?

Answer (score -1):

fadeOut() is a jQuery function. Once you include jQuery in your page you can do like the following:

```
<div id="clickme">
  Click here
</div>
<img id="book" src="book.png" alt="" width="100" height="123">
```

Your javascript would look like this:

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

This is taken from the [jQuery website](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/).

Comment: Have you included jQuery in the page?

Answer (score -1):

If jquery is OK, this works:

```
<div id="fader">Click to fade out</div>


$( "#fader" ).click(function() {
  $( "#fader" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/smandl/tj55xxc6/

Comment: This didn't make it fade out for me.